# What if Hong Kong airport protest happened in the US?

Tags: united-states, law, protests

I only mentioned Hong Kong here to provide context.

Here's what I am interested in:

What would happen if a similar protest happened in the US (from a legal perspective, by which I mean what of the following is allowed by the US law, and how would the US law treat these actions)?

And more specifically, let's say this protest partly involved the following:

1. Obstructing the functions of the airport
2. Disrupting public order
3. Beating walking-by passengers
4. Assaulting police officers

Comment: This question very much seems like an attempt to push a specific agenda. If you are actually interested in comparing attitudes on protests between the US and Hong Kong, and not just pushing talking points, take some time to edit out some of the leading statements and refocus your question on an on-topic political question

Comment: I advise you not to read too much into that. I simply care about what's going on and what to get some more insights on this matter. Sure, some statements might involve my personal opinion, but I don't think I can edit them out as they are mostly subconscious. Now that you probably have an idea about what I want to ask, I'd be happy to let you or someone else to edit this for me, as long as the edited version does not deviate too much or push some other agenda.

Comment: What is the question.  If the question is, would the US allow 1 airport to be taken by protesters?  well that depends entirely on how many protesters.  If JFK in NYC is taken over by protesters and the protesters are supported by 6 million NYC residents.  Then I guess the US will have to let the protest run its course.  if it is a protest by several hundred protesters..  they will most likely be cleared out.   The last time the US had such mass protests was during the Vietnam War, and the government ultimately yielded to the demands of the protesters.  Have you thought about doing that?

Comment: Not just the numbers, I am also talking about some violent actions. And what do you mean _have you thought about that_? A protest to stop a war is quite different from one to claim independence, especially if it's on your land.

Comment: @divibisan Question edited

Comment: Something I probably shouldn't post here: To those of you who thinks I am pushing an agenda and that I am trying to defame the US form of democracy, I am really not. On the contrary, while Hong Kong protesters claim they are following the western style to "strive for democracy", their violent actions are making Chinese people disgusted and angry, and the western democracy is therefore questioned and distrusted by more and more. This spreading of hate and distrust cannot be good for either side.

Comment: In this regard ,I don't think this protest is helping anyone: 1.it is damaging the reputation of western democracy; 2.it is obstructing Hong Kong people's life. Hence I honestly want to know whether they have gone too far by the western standards they claim to follow.

Comment: The context is important. Is the protest in response to a police state overreach that criminalizes ThoughtCrime® and are the police beating up the protesters? The American protesters would be armed and would pose a significant obstacle to any military or police aggression. The PLA has only to worry about international optics. Victory is assured since the HK protesters have no means to enforce their will. Because...you know...guns are bad n' stuff.

Comment: Even if the context was considered, I was more interested in what the Hong Kong police should react. Honestly, the PLA and central government have not interfered in anyway, and are unlikely to do so since the situation has been controled by a court order. It seems pointless to make this about the PLA.

Comment: "Beating walking-by passengers" [citation needed]

Comment: Sorry, but 'what if' questions like this can't be answered objectively, but only by speculation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The US has seen protests at airports, for example the recent [protests against Executive Order 13769](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protests_against_Executive_Order_13769#Impact). The number of protesters are probably not comparable though. While I can't find numbers on protesters at Hong Kong Airport, the aforelinked Wikipedia page lists over 2000 protestors at JFK.

Those protests were allowed, as far as I can see. Obviously, a few thousand people isn't that many for a large airport like JFK and the protesters didn't seem to try to block the airport.

The Wikipedia page does give us an insight into how authorities may deal with a few protesters having been arrested. From the [linked Los Angeles Times](https://www.latimes.com/local/lanow/la-me-lax-protest-20170129-story.html):

> At 10 p.m., two people were arrested for blocking the roadway, according to LAX police Officer Rob Pedregon. The two were cited and released.

As for a protest the scale of Hong Kong, I can speculate. With a protest  of that size, the authorities will have difficulty guaranteeing the safety of passengers and staff. Especially when you're with many people, you can easily overrun secured areas of an airport as airports aren't used to dealing with that.

Depending on the situation (that many don't just protest for fun, at risk of being arrested) it will probably be condemned by many and the authorities will work on clearing the airport (e.g. by detaining and citing protesters).